# Allow Access user to select Excel worksheet for linking

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So I am using VBA in Access to create linked tables between Excel and Access. Simple enough and as some online resources guided me I decided to utilize the *TransferSpreadsheet* command. So I ran some code to test out if I had the syntax correct and got this

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        "Link Name", "File Path", True, "Sheet Name!"
```

So that worked perfectly, but I wanted to automate it so someone who doesn't understand how to code can use the function. So for the file path I set up a file dialog box to come up so the user can select the excel file. Again worked great.

So now to the point, I want to create a dialog box for users to select the excel sheet to link as well. So essentially the user would select the excel file first and then select from a drop down box the sheet they want to link. Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing it. Here is my code so far:

```
Public Sub linksheet()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim strpath As String
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
fd.Title = "Select Routing File"



'get the number of the button chosen
Dim FileChosen As Integer

FileChosen = fd.Show

If FileChosen <> -1 Then

Else

strpath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        "Test Link", strpath, True, "Current!"

End If


End Sub
```

To add to this further I was attempting to utilize this code I found to get the names but I'm unsure how to store them as variables to use.

```
Public Function WorkSheetNames(strwspath As String) As Boolean
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strarray(25)

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strwspath, 0, True)
For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
Debug.Print xlSheet.Name

Next xlSheet
xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
End Function
```

What the above code does is list out each sheet name into the debug window, I just am finding it difficult to push those values to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need to store the sheet names in an array.  You could store them as a list in a string variable.  Then you could assign that string as the `RowSource` property of a combo box which allows the user to select one of the available sheets.

```vb
Dim strSheets As String
' adapt your existing code to use this ...
For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
    'Debug.Print xlSheet.Name
    strSheets = strSheets & ";" & xlSheet.Name
Next xlSheet
' discard leading semi-colon
strSheets = Mid(strSheets, 2)
```

After you have collected the sheet names, apply them as the combo box source.

```vb
' ComboName should have Value List as Row Source Type
Me.ComboName.RowSource = strSheets
```

Comment: I was unaware you could store them in a string variable like that. Thank you very much, it worked beautifully.